# What Font and Font size is used in iPhone SMS Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Does anyone know what Font Type (e.g. Arial, Courier new, etc) and Font Size (e.g. 9 pt, etc) is used in SMS Application of iPhone.

I need this info to create iPhone app which uses SMS API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it uses the system font and it's around 17.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
```

Just increase or decrease the font size and compare to Messages.app.